# How useful is PCA on its own?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, pca

In my machine learning course we have covered the key ideas behind principal component analysis. To round this part of the course off, we have learned to interpret the results of PCA, specifically using a biplot. Have I missed something, or is PCA mostly something that is used in conjuction with other ML methods to obtain a result? For example, in a biplot I can tell which observations are similar and how much each variable is contributing overall to a specific component, but how is this useful outside of employing something like clustering after-the-fact? From my point of view, it feels like PCA is the 'first-step' towards gaining some sort of insight but it doesn't tell you much that is useful on its own.

Comment: searching the site you can find many interesting threads on PCA, e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/101485/56940, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/448200/56940

Comment: PCA is not just for machine learning.  Popular questions here include https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca

Comment: What's your criterion for "a technique is useful on its own"? Without such a criterion, this question seems too broad.

Comment: Here is a well-cited paper as an example of PCA-based analysis that generated insights: Novembre, J., Johnson, T., Bryc, K. et al. Genes mirror geography within Europe. Nature 456, 98–101 (2008). https://doi.org/10.1038/nature07331