# How to interpret PCA loading and to relate it with correlation coefficient of associated independent variable with dependent variable

Tags: r, regression, pca

There are 2 sides to this question. On the first side, we are trying to run PCA.

While running PCA on a dataset having 62 independent variables (IVs), I have found that first component (PC1) explains ~90% of variance and that of variables or parameters contributing to this component, a variable say V1 has highest contribution. This means that V1 plays a big role in capturing major chunk of variance in the whole dataset. And hence, this V1 is important.

On the second side, we have found correlations of all IVs with the dependent variable (DV) Y, so that we can drop IVs with the correlation coefficients (with Y) less than a particular threshold, say 0.2. This exercise is done so that we have less number of IVs for building a model. Here, we find that if we consider this threshold, we have to drop V1.

This to me is surprising because V1 is very important when you look at it from PCA point of view but is very less important when you look at it from point of view of explaining DV.

Looking at these 2 sides, should we drop V1 now and why? Please share your inputs. If you need any other input from my end, please do ask.

PS - we are doing this exercise in R.

Comment: You seem to equate "contribution" with loading. Here come preliminary remarks. First, one should be aware that _loading_ [is not](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/143905/3277) eigenvector's element. Second, loading is the weight of dependency of a variable on a PC, not vice versa.

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141864

Comment: Thank you every one for replying. The links that you have shared are really useful.