# How to efficiently do PCA/SVD on dataset with thousands of features (both continuous and OHE)

Tags: regression, pca, high-dimensional

I am currently dealing with a dataset with about 300,000 records, there are a wide variety of categories in several columns and naturally when one-hot-encoding these the number of features increases into the 1000s.

Is there some sort of heuristic to find the optimal number of n_components for SVD that in turn minimises the MSE of the Linear Regression algorithm the data is then fed into after the decomposition?

I have tried a random search but 10 hours and counting and it still is nowhere near complete.

Comment: Since you want to regress the PCA outputs against some target variable, why not do that directly with [tag:partial-least-squares]?

Comment: Interesting and thank you for your suggestion, I just had a brief read over this but I'm still not sure what the best method is to find the optimal number for n_components even with PLS.

Comment: Optimal for what?

Comment: Minimizing MSE.

Comment: The MSE on the training data will be minimal if you include all of the features. You don't even need to do PCA.

Comment: Oh wow, okay, I always thought adding features willy nilly has the possibility of making the model perform worse.

Comment: If you're computing a new PCA/SVD for each choice of number of components, you're wasting time because you can re-use the first $k$ each time you want to add an additional component. Or just do PCA/SVD once for the largest number of components you care to compute, and then down-select to the $k$ you want to use. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Let me clarify, I want to minimise MSE on the testing data, of course it will be minimised regardless on training data.

Comment: PCA has no guarantee to improve the model. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141864/how-can-top-principal-components-retain-the-predictive-power-on-a-dependent-vari Feature selection might or might not be misguided.

Comment: Testing data is a different story. You can't know how the model predicts unseen data until you measure it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and sorry for posting a duplicate, I guess I just didn't know how to phrase the question when I was doing my research.