# Example datasets where PCA could improve or decrease performance of SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, svm, supervised-learning

Going through the top answers in [How can top principal components retain the predictive power on a dependent variable (or even lead to better predictions)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141864/how-can-top-principal-components-retain-the-predictive-power-on-a-dependent-vari), I understand that doing PCA and keeping the top k components may or may not improve classification performance of some supervised learning algorithm. For decision trees I can visualize how this could be the case, but I can't visualize a dataset (real or synthetic) where keeping the top $k$ components after PCA improves or decreases classification performance in SVM.